# JQuery Mobile content is merging not updating

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using:

```
$('#mypage').live("pageinit", function(){ 

$('#mypage').bind('pageshow', function() {

//json gets data here

}...etc
```

My problem is that the code is not getting a fresh page, just adding the same content every time I go to the page.

so:

Page load ... I go to #mypage and I get:

eg:

A. some content here

then if I load the page again I get 2 instances of the same:

A. some content here
A. some content here

and so on.

I need to it updates everytime but no merge the data.

Update:

Pageshow Code here:

```
 $('#mypage').bind('pageshow', function() {


    $.getJSON("http://mysite/api/get_data", function(data){
    var output = '';

    $.each(data.mydata, function(index, value){

    output += '<li><a href="#"><img src="'+value.thumbnail_url+'" /><h3>'+value.title+'</h3>'+value.body+'</a></li>';

    });
    $('#my_listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
    }).error(function(args) {
console.log(args);

});

});//end of pageshow
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you always append data to the my_listview element.

Replace the `$('#my_listview').append(output)` with `$('#my_listview').html(output)` and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: I updated my post. I've tested the solution locally. Could you check whether it fixes your issue? thanks